# How do I put my JS file on the top-level?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I'm trying out phoenix with service worker but I need to put the js file at the top-level. In Example `localhost:4000/sample.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serve a static assets at the top-level. Just add the file on `web/static/assets` and add that static file i.e. `sample.js` to the `only` option for Plug.Static in your app's endpoint like:

```
# => ./lib/my_app/endpoint.ex
plug Plug.Static,
at: "/", from: :learn_phoenix, gzip: false,
only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt sample.js) #=> added sample.js to this list. fonts, images, css and js are all directories
```